# Activity in android

Tags: android

I need to get all the data from web and display in the ui.currently, i did all this functionality in the activity onCreate() method.is that right? or else i can use other life cycle method like onResume(),onPause().please guide me.

Comment: You didn't ask a question, and you didn't post any code. If it works, I guess it's right. What issues are you having?

Comment: i don't have any issues. i need to understand what are the uses of other life cycle methods.now i am only using two methods onCreate(),onDestroy.

Comment: Any network requests should be made in an `AsyncTask` or a background `Thread`.  Unless you post some code though we can't really provide any concrete advice.

Answer (score 0):

Long lasting operations, such as download from the web, should newer be invoked from the UI thread (in onCreate, onResume, onPause). You should use background tasks to do this, or you will get ANR crash. One of possible ways is to use AsyncTask, as explained [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).